# Existence of Lebesgue integral with counting measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure.

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$.

1) Is it true that, for any $f$, $$\int_{\mathbb{N}} f(k)d\mu$$ exists (finite or infinite)?

2) Is it true that, for any $f$, if $$\int_{\mathbb{N}} f(k)d\mu$$ exists (finite or infinite) [*which is always the case if the answer to 1) is yes*], then $f$ is measurable?

Comment: Is $\mathcal{F}$ an arbitrary $\sigma$-algebra, or is it specified by the problem?

Comment: It is an arbitrary $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Then it could be $\mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{N}\}$, for which many functions are not measurable, like $f(x)=x$, and therefore the integral is not defined.

Comment: Ok, so 1)no, 2)yes? Could you make an example of non measurable function of $\mathcal{F}\equiv \{\emptyset, \mathbb{N}\}$?

Comment: Yes. But due to a quite avoidable reason. Because $\mu$ is defined on the $\sigma$-algebra $P(\mathbb{N})$. In that case all functions are measurable and the integral always exists (finite or infinite).

Comment: is $P(\mathbb{N})$ the power set of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: thanks, if you have time to post an answer I will validate it.

Comment: You can post yours. That way you make sure that you know how to prove that for $\mathbb{F}=P(\mathbb{N})$ the integrals exist.

Comment: Dumb question: How can you begin to speak of $f(k)$ if $f$ is not measurable? Or did you mean $\mathcal F-$measurable? I was thinking Borel-measurable.